# ISP router unreachable by PAT

Tags: cisco, routing, nat, troubleshooting

[image]
I just configured PAT in a router but it doesn't work ,,

I write this commands in R1

```
    access-list 4 permit 172.16.0.0 0.0.255.255
    ip nat pool AdeNet 80.80.10.20 80.80.10.20 netmask 255.255.255.255
    ip nat inside source list 4 pool AdeNet overload

    int s0/0/0
ip address 172.16.15.21 255.255.255.252
    ip nat outside

    int s0/0/1
ip address 172.16.15.2 255.255.255.252
    ip nat inside

    int s0/1/0
ip address 172.16.15.10 255.255.255.252
    ip nat inside

    int s0/1/1
ip address 172.16.15.17 255.255.255.252
    ip nat inside

    int f0/0
ip address 172.16.0.150 255.255.248.0
    ip nat inside
    exit
```

Here are the ISP router ip address

```
int s0/0/0
ip address 172.16.15.22 255.255.255.252
int f0/0
ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.0.0
```

80.80.10.20/32 is the public IP address for the NAT

These are the result of Show Run commands in 3 routers,, I hope it to be useful

```
ISP

FastEthernet0/0        10.10.1.1/16

Serial0/0/0            172.16.15.22/30
```

=========================================

```
R1

interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.0.150 255.255.248.0
 ip nat inside

interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address

interface FastEthernet0/1.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0

interface FastEthernet0/1.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.2.10 255.255.255.0

interface FastEthernet0/1.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 192.168.3.10 255.255.255.0

interface FastEthernet0/1.40
 encapsulation dot1Q 40
 ip address 192.168.4.10 255.255.255.0

interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 172.16.15.21 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 clock rate 2000000

interface Serial0/0/1
 ip address 172.16.15.2 255.255.255.252
 ip nat inside
 clock rate 64000

interface Serial0/1/0
 ip address 172.16.15.10 255.255.255.252
 ip nat inside
 clock rate 64000

interface Serial0/1/1
 ip address 172.16.15.17 255.255.255.252
 ip nat inside
 clock rate 64000

router ospf 12

 network 172.16.0.0 0.0.7.255 area 0
 network 172.16.15.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 172.16.15.8 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 172.16.15.16 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 172.16.15.20 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 192.168.0.0 0.0.7.255 area 0
exit
ip nat pool AdeNet 80.80.10.20 80.80.10.20 netmask 255.255.255.255
ip nat inside source list 4 pool AdeNet overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/0 
access-list 4 permit 172.16.0.0 0.0.255.255
access-list 4 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.7.255
```

=========================

R2

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.8.150 255.255.252.0

interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 172.16.15.1 255.255.255.252
 clock rate 2000000

interface Serial0/0/1
 ip address 172.16.15.5 255.255.255.252
 clock rate 64000

router ospf 12
 passive-interface FastEthernet0/0
 network 172.16.8.0 0.0.3.255 area 0
 network 172.16.15.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 172.16.15.4 0.0.0.3 area 0
```

I ospf area 0 to conncet all WAN networks and connected,

and static routing between ISP and the R1 router and default routing between ISP and R1

so , is there any thing missing , that prevent WANs from connecting the internet

Comment: What is the config on the ISP router?  Does it have a route to 80.80.10.20/32?  What address are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Mr.@Mike Pennington & Mr. @Ron I need help ,please

Comment: does it work without nat?   Can you ping 10.10.1.100 when NAT is turned off?  What are the routes of the ISP router?

Comment: Now, only R1 can ping 10.10.1.100 other router can't ping  ,,

Comment: this the result of : sh ip route in ISP router

     10.0.0.0/16 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       10.10.0.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
     80.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
S       80.80.10.20 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
     172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
S       172.16.0.0/16 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
C       172.16.15.20/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0

Comment: Why I can't ping from other routers except R1 !!

Comment: Looking at the messy, expensive design, I take it is a lab network. Why don't you post the entire config of ISP, R1 and that of one router sitting behind R1?

Comment: PAT is really made up. The RFCs use NAPT for what some people call PAT. See _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations, Section 4.1.2 Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663#section-4.1.2)_: "_NAPT extends the notion of translation one step further by also translating transport identifier (e.g., TCP and UDP port numbers, ICMP query identifiers). This allows the transport identifiers of a number of private hosts to be multiplexed into the transport identifiers of a single external address._" There is more in the RFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a default routing command in the R2 and it start ping to the ISP server ,, 
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/0

may I should write in all other routers , still don't understand why !! while I'm using OSPF protocol between routers , except ISP router ..

Comment: I should have seen that.  Sorry.  Your other routers don't know how to get to 10.10.1.0 because they don't have that route.  You can add it to R1 by the command "default-information originate" under the ospf configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. @Ron I do understand now why , and thanks for this magic command "default-information originate" I like it , it better than writing command in all other router :)) ,,
Thanks for giving me some of your time ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Change the static routes on the ISP router to use the next hop address 172.16.15.21 instead of the interface.

Comment: It doesn't work , still routers can't ping ISP router

Comment: Something is wrong with your configurations.  Can you post the complete configs for ISP, R1 and one other router?

Comment: Well ,, I hope it a little bit clear ,now.

Comment: Please post all of the ISP router

Comment: I wrote only a static routing between ISP and R1 
ip route 80.80.10.20 255.255.255.255 s0/0/0

Comment: It's hard to help you with partial information.  I think the problem is on the ISP router.

Comment: I didn't write any thing more in ISP router , is there any thing missing I should write it !! 
Actually , I'm just new learner so , if there is any book or articles that will help finish the configuration would be great ,, I'm sorry to bother you

Comment: You seem reluctant to post the config for that router.   If there is sensitive information on it, perhaps you could remove that information first, then post the rest.

Comment: It is just a learning network nothing sensitive I just want this network to be connected ,but seriously I didn't write any thing more , I need help so I shouldn't hide my configuration